# How to reset cache after each update in laravel cache

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, redis

I have a model that I used cache on it like below:

```
   public function fulfilledWish()
    {
        return Cache::remember('fulfilled_wish', 5, function () {
            return Model::with(['media', 'slug'])
                ->where('type_id', 2)
                ->take(4)
                ->get();
        });
```

I want the cache to be updated after each update or create happens on the model like `scout` in laravel. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: will this look for changes and use the cache again when models change ??

Comment: public function updatefulfilledWish($id, $num_of_views)
{
    if (Cache::has('fulfilled_wish.'.$id))
    {
        $fulfilled = Cache::get('fulfilled_wish.'.$id);
    }
    else
    {
        $fulfilled = Model::find($id);
    }
 //...
    $fulfilled->save();

    Cache::put('fulfilled_wish.'.$id, $fulfilled);
   return Cache::get('fulfilled_wish.*');
}

Comment: @uditrawat you can post it as answer. Don't forget to explain it.

Comment: put your each record with a unique key like record id followed by some suffix with periods and when you want to get that values do Cache::get('suffix.*'), worked for me.